# DropShadowEffect on custom window style

Tags: wpf

I have a custom Window style in wpf like so:

```
<Window Height="300" 
        x:Class="WpfDemo.NoteWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfDemo"
        Width="400"
        WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
        WindowStyle="None"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        AllowsTransparency="True">

    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="30"
                GlassFrameThickness="7"
            />
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:NoteWindow}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border BorderThickness="1">
                                <Border.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect Color="Red" BlurRadius="20" Direction="270" RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="4"/>
                                </Border.Effect>
                            </Border>
                            
                            <Border BorderThickness="1"
                                    Background="Black"
                                    BorderBrush="Gray">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" 
                                    BorderBrush="Red">
                                        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5 0">
                                                <TextBlock Text="Title"/>

                                                <TextBlock Text="Title2" Margin="15 0"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>

                                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                        <AdornerDecorator>
                                            <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                                        </AdornerDecorator>
                                    </Grid>

                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Content" />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

The problem is in DropShadowEffect on border. It is applied **inside of boder** (see picture[image]) and I need it to be applied outside. Like a window DropShadowEffect.

I've tried to use margins but it has not desired effect on this. I've tried to use DropShadowEffect on Window itself and it has same effect...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is far from a minimal reproducable example, we are missing all the colors etc.
Below I gave you a small example how you could achive what you are trying, now you can use this to adapt it to your need:

```
<Window>                      
    <Grid Background="Transparent" Margin="10">
            <Grid.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Color="Red" BlurRadius="20"  RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="0"/>
        </Grid.Effect>
        <Grid Height="200" Width="200" Background="Lime">
            <!-- Content here -->
                <TextBlock>Oh look its text</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

Comment: I can post code with dummy colors replacement. Your suggestion will not help as you use margin for make this kind of effect and in my implementation this can't be done because I use custom window chrome and want custom style with control template of window.

Comment: we are also missing notewindow etc. PLease strip it down to a minimal reproducable example

Comment: Why so? There is no importance in .cs file. It has nothing. I removed all bindings, you can just copy and paste it in your xaml and change name of class which is used to represent this xaml and also change style target type. Thats it nothing more.